# Generating Numpy Arrays of Complex Numbers

Tags: python, numpy, python-cmath

How can I quickly generate a `numpy` array of *calculated* complex numbers? By which I mean, the imaginary component is calculated from an array of values.

I have tried using python's literal `j` without luck. It seems to only accept float and int cases. `cmath` refuses to handle arrays. Below is my current attempt.

```
import numpy as np
import cmath

E0, k, z, w = np.ones(4)

def Ex(t):
    exp = complex(0,k*z-w*t)
    return E0*np.exp(exp)

t = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
E = Ex(t)
```

this nets the following error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8444/3633149291.py in Ex(t)
      7 
      8 def Ex(t):
----> 9     exp = complex(0,k*z-w*t)
     10     return E0*np.exp(exp)
     11 

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am also open to solutions which *do not* utilize `cmath` but I had no luck forming arrays of complex numbers without the following workaround:

```
times = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
E = [Ex(t) for t in times]
```

Comment: `complex(1,3)` is a python function that takes 2 numbers and returns one complex one.  It isn't designed to take numpy arrays (or lists).  But `1j` can be used in computations, multiplying and adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is `exp = 1j*(k*z-w*t)`.

Comment: Or, as one line, just `E0 * np.exp( 1j * (k * z - w * t) )`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after. Couldn't find a use like this in the documentation, or in random searching online.